# Configuring NextCloud with Amazon S3 and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, synchronization, nextcloud

i was looking through the web about how to connect NextCloud to S3 and i found it [over here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_files/primary_storage.html#amazon-s3) i even found some topics on the forums explain how to do that, which is great.

but my solution also depend on Amazon RDS, i didn’t find much about it, so how to configure RDS to be the primary NextCloud database ? (in the same manner of S3 for example S3 configuration was to be made before even creating an admin user, that i saw on the forum) and if its possible, what are the DBs that are supported by NextCloud?

after that i tried to connect the NextCloud to the Amazon RDS but didn’t work  at the beginning i installed the NextCloud following the [NextCloud installation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html) but i didn’t install mariadb-server since i already have my DB which is the RDS, PHP 7 is installed, and php7.0-mysql is also installed, and mysql pdo is enabled, if i run sudo php --ini i have
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
and if i run the command: sudo php -m i have
pdo_mysql , that means both are enabled
and at my config file i have the following

```
<?php
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'dbname' => 'dmname',
  'dbhost' => '**********.rds.amazonaws.com:port-number',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => '********',
  'dbpassword' => '********',
  'installed' => false,
```

i even tried the config

```
<?php
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '12.0.4.3',
  'dbname' => 'dbname',
  'dbhost' => 'http://**********.rds.amazonaws.com',
  'dbport' => 'port-number',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => '********',
  'dbpassword' => '********',
```

yet i keep getting the exception

```
{"reqId":"jUI5gpnDa3jRzK9N4crh","level":3,"time":"2018-01-29T12:43:01+00:00","remoteAddr":"194.165.136.114","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/nextcloud\/index.php","message":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\DBALException: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver at \/var\/www\/nextcloud\/lib\/private\/DB\/Connection.php#61","userAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/63.0.3239.132 Safari\/537.36","version":""}
  'installed' => true,
```

and i even installed mariaDB, `mariadb-server`
yet the same problem keeps coming.

then i ran the command on the server’s terminal and i was able to connect to the RDS from the server itself, meaning nothing is blocking the RDS within the server
the command is: mysql -u username -h *******.rds.amazonaws.com -p

and the response was like the following:

```
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is ***
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
```

any help would be great